# .NET 4.5 installation on server running .net 2.0 and 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-4.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm about to install .net 4.5 on a windows 2008 server with .net 2.0 and .net 4.0 already installed. I also have over 10 web forms applications running on iis. Microsoft said that the in-place installation of 4.5 over 4.0 is completely backwards compatible, but I still want to know if I should have any other concerns before I go ahead with the install. Is everything going to break? I'm so scared!

Comment: Don't do that unless you have a good reason to.

Comment: @HighCore I want to use some of the features that are only available in 4.5, so is there a reason behind why I shouldn't be doing that? THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be ready for the unexpected. You have several applications running in that server.

And see [MSDN about that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx)